# Choosing power supply with sensor

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, sensor, load

I have a sensor that requires 9-30 VDC power, 600 mW at 24 VDC nominal voltage. I have a power supply that can source up to 15 VDC and up to 400 mW in power. If 24 VDC is the nominal voltage of the sensor at 600 mW, then I assume that it requires 25 mA as the nominal current. For my power supply, if I were to set 15 VDC, then I could source 400mw/15V = 26.7mA of current. I know that the 15 V is a lower potential, and thus the current would change as well, but would it still be enough to power? My main questions are these:

1. Does the load require 600 mW or 25 mA for power? What exactly "powers" it?
2. What is the meaning of the 9-30 VDC power? Does it somehow change the resistance to allow more current if I am using a lower voltage power supply?

I'd greatly appreciate any clarification with these!

Comment: What kind of sensor?

Answer (score 2):

You are making assumptions about your sensor that may not be valid. If you reduce the input voltage it is possible that the input current could go up, so that the power consumption remains relatively constant. So, no, based on the information you have provided we can't say that your proposed arrangement will work. We can't say how the sensor current will change or why it is changing in a particular way. Just not enough information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The input requirements of the sensor on the spec sheet says 9-30 VDC, 600 mW at 24 VDC nominal voltage. There is no other information on the input power. I am trying to figure out if my power supply could power it.

Answer (score 0):

If you post the datasheet it would be easier to help you. But given the information you've given us, it's likely that your power supply won't be able to give enough power without damaging itself, or make the sensor operate reliably.

If the datasheet says that the sensor needs 600mW of power at 24 volts, you need a power supply rated for 600mW of power. It might be that the sensor takes in less current at lower voltages, but we can't know that without the datasheet.

So to answer your two questions:

1. The power powers it.
2. It probably has an internal voltage regulator, that can take 9-30VDC and turn it into the voltage it needs (likely 24VDC, since it's the one that's specified).

I would get a new power supply.

Answer (score 0):

The following sensor specifications are to be considered while selecting the power supply:

1. Operating voltage - May be a fixed voltage or a range e.g. (24 V DC) or (10...30 V DC).
2. Current consumption - Or no-load supply current e.g. (< 15 mA) or (< 15 mA at 24 V DC).
3. Load current - Or switching current / operating current e.g. (0...100mA) or (max. 100 mA) or (100 mA short-circuit / overload protected).

The actual load current may depend on the application (lower current while driving a digital input or higher while driving a relay).

However it would be safe to consider the sum of no-load current and load current per sensor while selecting the power supply (for this example it would be 15 + 100 = 115 mA).